# LINQ запрос к БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, linq, linq2sql

Делаю запрос к БД, сначала беру данные из таблицы `Technologies`, далее идет поиск, сортировка + разбиваю на страницы. Получается очень много похожего кода.

```
switch (sort) {
  case "Low":
    items.Tvsets = db.Technologies.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(tech))
      .Include(p => p.Tvsets.Select(x => x.Company))
      .FirstOrDefault() ? .Tvsets
      .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search) ||
        x.Company.Name.Contains(search) ||
        x.Technology.Name.Contains(search))
      .OrderBy(x => x.Price)
      .Skip((pageInfo.PageNumber - 1) * pageInfo.PageSize)
      .Take(GetAll(pageInfo.TotalItems, pageInfo.PageSize, pageInfo.PageNumber))
      .ToList();

    return View(items);

  default:
    ViewBag.Sort = "High";
    items.Tvsets = db.Technologies.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(tech))
      .Include(p => p.Tvsets.Select(x => x.Company))
      .FirstOrDefault() ? .Tvsets
      .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search) ||
        x.Company.Name.Contains(search) ||
        x.Technology.Name.Contains(search))
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Price)
      .Skip((pageInfo.PageNumber - 1) * pageInfo.PageSize)
      .Take(GetAll(pageInfo.TotalItems, pageInfo.PageSize, pageInfo.PageNumber))
      .ToList();

    return View(items);
}
```

Как можно уменьшить код? Может быть есть какие-либо паттерны или другие способы?

Comment: Обратите внимание, что вы затягиваете из СУБД на клиент коллекцию Tvsets целиком без фильтрации на стороне базы. Учитывая что записей достаточно много для того чтобы их разбивать на страницы - это грубая ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
var tvSets = db.Technologies
               .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(tech))
               .Include(p => p.Tvsets.Select(x => x.Company))
               .FirstOrDefault() ? .Tvsets
               .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search) ||
                           x.Company.Name.Contains(search) ||
                           x.Technology.Name.Contains(search)).AsQueryable();
if (sort == "Low")
{
    tvSets = tvSets.OrderBy(x => x.Price);
}
else
{
    ViewBag.Sort = "High";
    tvSets = tvSets.OrderByDescending(x => x.Price);
}
items.Tvsets = tvSets.Skip((pageInfo.PageNumber - 1) * pageInfo.PageSize)
                     .Take(GetAll(pageInfo.TotalItems, pageInfo.PageSize, pageInfo.PageNumber))
                     .ToList();
return View(items);
```

Т.е. выделяем общее в обоих запросах, а различие в зависимости от параметра. В данном случае у вас всего одно различие, в сортировке. Вот ее и выделили. Запрос не выполнится до тех пор, пока не будет вызван .ToList(). До этих пор его можно собирать кусочками, не опасаясь, что на сервер уйдет кусок запроса.

Comment: Благодарю! Это именно то, что мне нужно! Отдельное спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: Пояснение по поводу *"запрос не выполнится пока не сделали `ToList`"* - неверное. `FirstOrDefault` столь же успешно выполняет запрос!

Comment: Да. Упустил этот момент. Спасибо